# How do I remove the quotes from req.query.id; node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to set up some simple pagination on a mysql query using node.js.

My query gathers about 100 rows from the data base and I want to show them in a table 12 rows at a time.  I have it setup so that the first time the query runs it looks for the value of req.query.id if it does not exist or if it is null it sets a variable (p) to 0 then runs the query with a limit clause of LIMIT p,12  this works goos so far.  Now I pass p+12 in the response to the view and store it in a hidden field called id.  When the next page button is clicked it routes back to the same page except now that req.query.id is no longer null I set p to equal req.query.id (12 the first time, 24 the next time and so on) but when I run the query it seems like p is being given a value of '12' with the single quotes.  This causes mysql to trow an error at LIMIT '12',12.  My question is how would I remove the single quotes from the req.query.id value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string value to integer.

```
req.query.id = parseInt(req.query.id)
```